# data.table column subsetting returning 0 rows

Tags: r, data.table

```
BL_data[, (!(names(BL_data) %in% 'IV')), with = F]
```

returns:

```
uuid  city birth_year education_level employment_type gender marital_status number_of_children monthly_debt_expenses
1: 1uvsq4y0 Delhi       1996    no education        salaried female            yes                  2                   528
   net_monthly_income monthly_rent
1:               4247         1563
```

Vs

```
BL_data[, !(names(BL_data) %in% 'IV'), with = F]
```

returns

```
Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)
```

I couldn't understand this behavior even after reading the documentation. Any explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra parentheses `(...)` indicate that it should be evaluated in the parent frame.

In your second example, it is evaluating in the environment being the data.table `BL_data` itself, which is fine for accessing e.g. columns such as `city` directly.